# How do you get holder wallet address from token account data?

Tags: geyser

I'm trying to run geyser plugin to listen in on account data updates, and my plan is to build an index with holder wallet address as the key, and list of owned token accounts as the value.

So say if a token account (nft) is transferred, what account data do I need to look at in order to build my index?